# How to pass list<object> param generically

Tags: java

This is my generic construtor

```
public TreeContainer(Class<T> type, Object parentPID, List<Object> childrensPID) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    super(type);
    this.parentPID = parentPID;
    this.childrensPID = childrensPID;
}
```

This is my bean (with getter setter)

```
public class DirectoryBean implements Serializable {
      private long id;
      private String name;
      private DirectoryBean parent;
      private List<DirectoryBean> childrens;    
}
```

I create a new Tree Container like this

```
TreeContainer<DirectoryBean> treeContainer = new TreeContainer<DirectoryBean>(DirectoryBean.class,"parent", "childrens" );
```

But the "childrens" parameter is illegal, how can i pass the list params in this situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constructor expects this

```
List<Object> childrensPID
```

but you are passing a String "childrens".
You can get around it by putting it in a list.

```
List<Object> childrens = new ArrayList<Object>();
childrens.add("childrens");
new TreeContainer<DirectoryBean>(DirectoryBean.class,"parent", childrens );
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably would be sufficient to change it to `? extends Object`. However, the purpose of using generics here is to limit the range of data types. You'd be better off doing something like:

`? extends BeanBaseObject`